# Webservice PHP Soap

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Opa Pessoal, Boa Tarde!

Estou tendo dificuldade para consumir um webservice.

Fis um programa basico para consumir mas está apresentando a seguinte mensagem de erro:
"O Request deverá ser informado".

Não consegui entender o que seria este request.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu fonte:

```
  $mensagem = array('Emitir' =>array('Aliquota'=>0,
                               'Atividade'=>1.03,
                               'CEPPrestacaoServico'=>'',
                               'ChaveAutenticacao'=>'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                               'CidadePrestacaoServico'=>'',
                                'EnderecoPrestacaoServico'=>'',
'EstadoPrestacaoServico'=>'',
'Homologacao'=>true,
'InformacoesAdicionais'=>'teste de geracao de nota webservice',
'NotificarTomadorPorEmail'=>false,
'NumeroCei'=>0,
'SimplesNacional'=>false,
'SubstituicaoTributaria'=>false,
'CNPJ'=>'',
'CPF'=>'22702816835',
'DDD'=>'11',
'Email'=>'samuelvincenzome@gmail.com',
'Bairro'=>'presidente altino',
'CEP'=>'06216280',
'Cidade'=>'Osasco',
'Complemento'=>'casa',
'Estado'=>'SP',
'Logradouro'=>'teste',
'Numero'=>'123',
'Pais'=>'Brasil',
'TipoLogradouro'=>'Rua',
'InscricaoMunicipal'=>0,
'Nome'=>'Samuel de Vincenzo',
'Telefone'=>'972858650',
'TomadorEstrangeiro'=>false,
'Valor'=>100.00,
'ValorCSLL'=>0.00,
'ValorCofins'=>0.00,
'ValorDeducao'=>0.00,
'ValorINSS'=>0.00,
'ValorIR'=>0.00,
'ValorOutrosImpostos'=>0.00,
'ValorPisPasep'=>0.00,
'ValorRepasse'=>0.00));



$function = 'Emitir';

$options = array('location' => 'https://nfe.osasco.sp.gov.br/EISSNFEWebServices/NotaFiscalEletronica.svc');



   $client = new SoapClient('https://nfe.osasco.sp.gov.br/EISSNFEWebServices/NotaFiscalEletronica.svc?Wsdl');

   $result = $client->__soapCall($function,$mensagem,$options);       


   echo 'Response: ';
   print_r($result);
```

Obrigado

Samuel

Comment: O erro parece ser do proprio `NotaFiscalEletronica.svc?Wsdl`, ou seja não é no seu PHP, eu acho. Como não conheço esse serviço não posso informar o que falta, mas é possivel que a DOC deles tenha algo que informe sobre este erro.

Comment: tente utilizar esse link https://nfe.osasco.sp.gov.br/EissnfeWebServices/NotaFiscalEletronica.svc?singleWsdl